# Flush Messages in wildfly 10 (activemq) programmatically

Tags: activemq-classic, wildfly-10

I'm using wildfly 10. I'm developing a management console to manage queue. I want to know how to **flush the queue programmatically** (like flush option provided in wildfly 10 management console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMX Api can be used which will perform mbean operation